# IBM Watson Assistant: How to get json response into button options

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, watson-dialog, watson-assistant-solutions

I'm working on a flight reservation chatbot using Watson Assistant chatbot that connects to IBM Cloud SDK through Java API. My idea is to get the API results, from a client's flight search, and set the json response into different button options using Watson. The problem is that I'm not finding a way to do it, can someone help me?

Comment: How are you using Watson Assistant, how is it integrated? You can generate buttons in your chat app

Comment: I'm using twilio to make the integration with whatsapp business. The API calls are made through a middleware and I format the json that is sended to Watson through the middleware too, I did this because I couldn't find an easy way to use the original json to show the information to the client/user

Comment: Are you calling out to the cloud function from within Watson Assistant? If so you can encode the dialog node that holds the results, with buttons that are labeled with the results of the cloud function.

Comment: No, I'm using a client application to invoke watson assistant through the ibm cloud sdk